# wordpress custom post type loop does not work with pagination

Tags: wordpress

Working with a custom post type, which works perfect. All custom posts are showen, but I cant get the pagination to work correct.

Once I click on the next the page is redirected to /page/2/ which does not exict.

Untill now I could not find a working solution online so why is this not working?

Here's the code that I use:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'projects', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'          => $paged                                
) );

// the loop 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    the_title(); 

endwhile; 

    next_posts_link( '&larr; '.__( 'next' , 'ff' ) ,  $query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( '&larr; '.__( 'prev' , 'ff' ) , $query->max_num_pages );

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code for pagination :

```
$total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
```

Another option is You can add rewrite rule in your function.php

```
  function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Modify it as per your requirement and then flush it

```
<?php flush_rewrite_rules( $hard ); ?>
```

For More information, you can refer this link for WordPress documentation: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Hope this will gives you the solution.

Comment: This works, but there's an issue, this will ad tralling slashes to the url....site.com/projects//page/2, site.com/projects///page/3 and so on.

Comment: I have tried this but this will give me an 'page not found' error

Comment: Ahh, Now got your point. I have updated my answer with another option for solution.

Comment: Try my second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code for custom post pagination :

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if ($paged == "1") {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'projects', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => 0                               
) );
} else {
    $offset = $paged * 5;
    $offset = $offset - 5;
   $query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'projects', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => $offset                                
) );
}

if ($query->have_posts()) :
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    /*Your Code */

endwhile;
?>
<div class="pagination-grp">
    <?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    //$i=1;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'prev_text' => __('<'),
        'next_text' => __('>'),
        'total' => $query->max_num_pages

    ));
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: When clicking to the next page it will give me an 'page not found' error